# CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, ienumerable

I'm using this code but doesn't work

```
List<UrunListesi> DegiskenListesi = new List<UrunListesi>();
DegiskenUrunListesi = (from UL in DB.UrunListesi
                       where IDListesi.Contains(UL.KategoriID.ToString()) && UL.Durum == true
                       orderby UL.id descending
                       select UL).ToList();
```

Browser Error

> "CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type
>   `System.Collections.Generic.List<UrunListesi>`
>   [c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll]' to
>   `System.Collections.Generic.List<UrunListesi>`
>   [c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll]'"

I tried this line but this didn't work too

```
IEnumerable<UrunListesi> DegiskenUrunListesi = null;
DegiskenUrunListesi = (from UL in DB.UrunListesi
                       where IDListesi.Contains(UL.KategoriID.ToString()) && UL.Durum == true
                       orderby UL.id descending
                       select UL).ToList();
```

dbcontext

```
public partial class MySiteDBEntities : DbContext
    {
        public MySiteDBEntities()
            : base("name=MySiteDBEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<AnaBanner> AnaBanner { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<BankaListesi> BankaListesi { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<KategoriListesi> KategoriListesi { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<KrediKartiOdemeleri> KrediKartiOdemeleri { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<TaksitOranTablosu> TaksitOranTablosu { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<UrunResimListesi> UrunResimListesi { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<UrunYorumlari> UrunYorumlari { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<MarkaListesi> MarkaListesi { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<IlceListesi> IlceListesi { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<SehirListesi> SehirListesi { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<UlkeListesi> UlkeListesi { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<UyeBilgileri> UyeBilgileri { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<KullaniciListesi> KullaniciListesi { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<SepetListesi> SepetListesi { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<BinListesi> BinListesi { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<RenkListesi> RenkListesi { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<UrunListesi> UrunListesi { get; set; }
    }
```

UrunListesi Class

```
public partial class UrunListesi
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> MarkaID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> KategoriID { get; set; }
    public string UrunAdi { get; set; }
    public string UrunKodu { get; set; }
    public string UrunAciklama { get; set; }
    public string AnaResim { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Fiyat { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Indirimli { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> IndirimliFiyat { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Kdv { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Iskontolu { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> IskontoOrani { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> StokAdet { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> RenkID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> EviminoImalati { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> KargoBedava { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> KargoFiyati { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> KargoSuresi { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> FirsatUrunu { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> FirsatBaslangicTarihi { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> FirsatBitisTarihi { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> KampanyaliUrun { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> KampanyaBitis { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> UrunHit { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> KayitTarih { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Durum { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> UrunKey { get; set; }
}
```

need help, Thank you.

Comment: Weird, that doesn't make sense to me. What happens if you just use `var`? Are you sure this is the line that's producing the error? The exception you posted indicates two of the exact same types.

Comment: Are these `IEnumerable<UrunListesi>`  and `DB.UrunListesi` referring to same type? I doubt that.

Comment: Please post the error message ***exactly*** as it appears.  Copy and paste is preferred.

Comment: Try ToList<UrunListesi>() instead of ToList();

Comment: this code not working sometimes. when click login.aspx page, when error page come back no problem. working. i think problem not about this code ?
Sory, bad english :)

Comment: are you sure in dbcontext you defined the same type of UrunListesi ?

Comment: @Hamza can you share dbcontext and UrunListesi model?

Comment: @S.Petrosov, Unfortunately not working :(

Comment: I solved the problem.

I have UrunListesi Class in dbcontext. i have same name UrunListesi.aspx file. Thats the whole problem.

thanks for all answer.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var list = (from UL in DB.UrunListesi
            where IDListesi.Contains(UL.KategoriID.ToString()) && UL.Durum == true
            orderby UL.id descending
            select UL).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

I have UrunListesi Class in dbcontext. i have same name UrunListesi.aspx file. Thats the whole problem.

thanks for all answer.